# Does everyone have to run all the contracts?

Tags: mining, consensus, nodes

Does everyone have to run all the contracts or can nodes pick and choose what contracts they want to run?

I'm still trying to wrap my head around how many nodes need to run a contract before I can reasonably know it'll go through.